# Send message to selected contacts in Android

Tags: android, message, android-contacts

I want to build an application, to send message to selected contacts with the help  when app activated.I made an app that select contacts but not able to add messaging feature, when clicked on Activation toggle key

```
 textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_number1);
 textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_number2); 

public void pickAContactNumber(View view) 
{ 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT1);
 }
```

Comment: textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_number1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_number2);

-----------------------------------------------------------

 public void pickAContactNumber(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT1);

    }

Comment: what do you mean by "messaging"? sending the selected contacts an sms message?

Answer (score 1):

As you have call activity for getting contact, you will get contact in onActivityResult method and from there you can implement your logic as below,

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

     switch (reqCode) {
         case (PICK_CONTACT1) :
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                   null, null);
                            phones.moveToFirst();
                            cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                            System.out.println("number is:"+cNumber);
                    sendMessage(cNumber);

                    }
                    //String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
           }
           break;
      }
  }

  public void sendMessage(String number)
  {
  }
```